# What is the deffered load in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, load

What is the deffered load in NHibernate? what is it's usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to [Lazy Loading](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx)?

Essentially it means that the data for the object is not loaded from the database until you actually need it.

If you had a large object graph for example Customers > Orders > OrderItems > Product you might not need to load all the data from Orders, OrderItems, Product if you are just altering the customers last name for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to *Lazy loading*

This [article](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx) would help you understand that

Answer (score 0):

Deferred loading is alternative naming of lazy loading.

[Lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)

[Understanding Lazy loading](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html)

[How to implement lazy loading in C#](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Framework/366_What_is_Lazy_Loading_or_Deferred_Loading_How_to_implement_Lazy_Loadingin_Net_with_C_.aspx)